# Can we use than as a contradiction instead of comparison?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a team chat, I found the following sentence written by a colleague of mine:

```
Hi, just for the clarity of the team, Marcos found the issue with another column than what is mentioned in the description of the issue.
```

I always used **than** as a mean of comparison but in the above sentence it seems like using than as a contradiction. So is this a permitted usage of than? I feel like this is a very colloquial usage of this word in a particular region that I am not used to.

Comment: It's still a comparative construction.

Answer (score 1):

"Than" isn't only used in comparisons - we use "*other than*" in connection with exceptions, exclusions or omissions, for example, "*I have a brother other than the ones you already met*".

A more idiomatic way to say what your colleague meant would be:

> Marcos found the issue with **a column other than** what is mentioned in the description of the issue.

"Another" is a contraction of "an other", so it could be argued his original sentence was fine - he was saying that he found "one other column than" the ones already known. It just isn't quite idiomatic.

I would also have preferred if he had said "other than *those* mentioned", or "other than *the one* mentioned", depending on how many columns were already listed.